# React mutable reference, update state in function

Tags: reactjs

I have much trouble understanding state and mutability in react functions. I asked a question before but wanted to ask a new question because I am not understanding what the underlying issue is.

I have the following code:

```
  const {userInfo} = useSession(); //<-- wrapper for useContext, gives some object with user info
  console.log(userInfo); //<--- correct, updates every time

  const haalDataOp = async () => {
    console.log(userInfo.enelogic); //<--- old value displaying, never updates
  }
  return <button onClick={haalDataOp} />
```

I have a mechanism where I listen to changes in userInfo object (in Firestore) and update the context accordingly. So when I update my userinfo object, I see the correct value logging (line 2). But, the function (which was called through a button click) has an old value of userInfo. So when I click a button which triggers `haalDataOp` it console.logs the old userInfo value.

In the old question, a guy suggested to use `useRef`. Why is that? His example worked, but I am not understanding why I should use `useRef` here because below snippet works (and doesnt need useRef):

```
  const [value, setValue] = useState(1);

  const handleClick = () => {
    console.log(value);
    setValue(value + 1)
  }
```

Comment: Where are you calling haalDataOp?

Comment: On a button click, Ill add to my question

Comment: When (and where) are you updating userInfo? (and also how?)

Comment: You need to provide more context like when you are clicking on the button, has an update occured?

Comment: For your function haalDataOp to see the change, the component must be rerendered.

Comment: I tried to explain in the question. UseSession is returning react context from a parent component. I am changing the state by manually changing state in the database (firestore), from which an event listener updates the context state. After updating, it logs the correct new value, but if I then click the button, the old one logs (jnside haalDataOp)

Answer (score 0):

```
  const [value, setValue] = useState(1);

  const handleClick = () => {
    console.log(value);
    setValue(value + 1)
  }
```

is a good approach. You can use either `useState` or `useRef`, they are very similar, with the difference that useState triggers a re-render. `useRef` is useful when you want to keep an instance variable around ([react doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-there-something-like-instance-variables))